# Add spacing before and after `\hline` in an array in an equation

Tags: spacing, amsmath, arrays

I'm trying to add a little bit of space before and after the `\hline` in this matrix:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500


\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
    \boldsymbol{J^{-1}} = \\   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial P_2} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial P_2} &
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial Q_2} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial Q_2} \\
    \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{11}^\prime} & \vdots & \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{21}^\prime} & \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial P_n} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial P_n} &
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial Q_n} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial Q_n} \\
    \hline
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial P_2} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial P_2} &
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial Q_2} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial Q_2} \\
     \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{12}^\prime} & \vdots& \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{22}^\prime} & \vdots \\
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial P_n} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial P_n} &
     \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial Q_n} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial Q_n} \\ 
    \end{array} \right]
    \\\label{eq:Jinv}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Before]

At the moment, I've done this:

```
... \\[0.5em]
\hline
&&&&&\\[-0.8em]
...
```

Which works:

[image: Hack]

but is a bit messy. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a couple of new commands.  I'm not sure whether this is better than your own solution, but it is an alternative approach.

The two of the new commands are `\bottomstrut` and `\topstrut`.  The third command combines these two with a new line and an `hline` for your multiline environment.  The following two are examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500

\newcommand{\bottomstrut}[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\topstrut}[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\dividerline}[2]{\bottomstrut{#1}\\\hline\topstrut{#2}}


\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

Example with \verb=\bottomstrut{2ex}\\\hline\topstrut{3ex}=

\begin{multline}
    \boldsymbol{J^{-1}} = \\   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial P_2} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial P_2} &
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial Q_2} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial Q_2} \\
    \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{11}^\prime} & \vdots & \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{21}^\prime} & \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial P_n} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial P_n} &
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial Q_n} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial Q_n} 
    \bottomstrut{2ex}\\\hline\topstrut{3ex}
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial P_2} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial P_2} &
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial Q_2} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial Q_2} \\
     \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{12}^\prime} & \vdots& \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{22}^\prime} & \vdots \\
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial P_n} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial P_n} &
     \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial Q_n} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial Q_n} \\ 
    \end{array} \right]
    \\\label{eq:Jinv:1}
\end{multline}

Example with \verb=\dividerline{2ex}{3ex}=

\begin{multline}
    \boldsymbol{J^{-1}} = \\   \left[ \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial P_2} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial P_2} &
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial Q_2} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial Q_2} \\
    \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{11}^\prime} & \vdots & \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{21}^\prime} & \vdots \\
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial P_n} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial P_n} &
    \frac{\partial \delta_2}{\partial Q_n} & \hdots & \frac{\partial \delta_n}{\partial Q_n} 
    \dividerline{2ex}{3ex}
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial P_2} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial P_2} &
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial Q_2} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial Q_2} \\
     \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{12}^\prime} & \vdots& \vdots & \boldsymbol{J_{22}^\prime} & \vdots \\
    \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial P_n} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial P_n} &
     \frac{1}{|V_2|}\frac{\partial |V_2|}{\partial Q_n} & \hdots & \frac{1}{|V_n|}\frac{\partial |V_n|}{\partial Q_n} \\ 
    \end{array} \right]
    \\\label{eq:Jinv:2}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'd read about "struts" but didn't know how to use them, or that they worked in this situation.